# My Serial Command line for Arduino doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: c++, c, arduino, serial-port

please help I'm blind

```
void commandline() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
    String commandvar = Serial.readString();

    Serial.print(command);
    Serial.print(" | ");
    Serial.println(commandvar);

    if ( command == "fans" || command == "Fans" || command == "FANS" )
    {
      Serial.println("Command Recognized");
      if ( commandvar == "on" || commandvar == "On" || commandvar == "ON" )
      {
        Serial.println("                  Fans are now ON");
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      }
      else if ( commandvar == "off" || commandvar == "Off" || commandvar == "OFF" )
      {
        Serial.println("                  Fans are now OFF");
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      }
      else
      {
      Serial.println("commandvar isn't valid");
    }
  }
```

when i look at the serial console and send "fans on", the console spits out

```
fans | on

Command Recognized
commandvar isn't valid
```

any help would be very much appreciated

=========================

Extra Info

1) I'm calling commandline() from loop() every 10 miliseconds

2) The fans command isn't the only command I have it's just that I have to convert them to work with the new command variables I created

3) I'm Using the Arduino Uno Rev 3

Comment: Common sense would say that if you're getting an unrecognized command, you may want to output it so you can see if what you think you sent is what your code thinks it receives, wouldn't it? Learning to debug using simple techniques is a valuable skill you should probably make an effort to learn.

Comment: Are you sure there is any C++ involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is a hint: There is a blank line. Says to me that `commandvar = "on\n"` and therefore `!= "on"`

You can confirm this is the problem by checking the length of the string - if it is > 2 then there is some special character(s) in there that you were not expecting. If the characters are just white space, then you probably just need `commandvar.trim()` to get just the important part (i.e. no whitespace)